# c++ How to add dinamically a label to a groupbox and set its postion

Tags: forms, visual-studio, controls, position, c++-cli

Hi guys I want the user to choose a list of files (txt file) and I wanna show the path of those file in a groupbox, I can do this perfectly in c# but I am having some problem with c++\cli 
p.s I working in visual studio 2017 community

this is my code:

```
openFileDialog1 = gcnew System::Windows::Forms::OpenFileDialog();
openFileDialog1->InitialDirectory = DefaultProgramPath;
openFileDialog1->FileName = "";
openFileDialog1->Filter = "ESA Files (*.esa)|*.esa|txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
openFileDialog1->FilterIndex = 1;
openFileDialog1->RestoreDirectory = true;

if (openFileDialog1->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK)
{
    String^ toBeAdded= openFileDialog1->FileName;
    Label^job = gcnew  Label();
    job->Text = toBeAdded;

    job->Location.X = 150;
    job->Location.Y = 250;
    groupBox1->Controls->Add(job);
}
```

with this code the label is added to the groupbox But I can't set its position properly within it

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`System.Drawing.Point`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.point) is a value type (`struct` in C#, `value class`/`value struct` in C++/CLI), therefore the property [`Location`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.location) is returning a *copy* of its current location. In order to update it, you need to set the entire value type at once.

```
Point newLocation;
newLocation.X = 150;
newLocation.Y = 250;
job->Location = newLocation;
```